# How to implement REST API Call Tracing

Tags: rest, trace

I have a couple of microservices and would like to be able to see every endpoint that a specific API call goes through. In essence, given a requestID, I should be able to generate a sequence diagram of its journey.

Research suggests that I need to attach a UUID to a every request, then I can log the request to [ELK](https://www.elastic.co/elk-stack) wherever I am interested. Seems logical.

My concerns:

1. How do you guarantee that some intermediate service or function does not strip or change this requestID?
2. Is it a good idea to generate the ID in the client or the API gateway?
3. Where would you keep this requestID: header? body? url parameter?

Rather than hypothetical recommendations (which I have already considered), I would appreciate real-world experience from someone who has done this. Thanks.

Comment: Your question is a little too broad for a concrete answer. A lot will depend on the software stack you use. I have used Zipkin with Spring Boot with great success in the past. Zipkin has support for a wide variety of systems and programming languages. It can also be used to instrument more than just HTTP communication between services: I have used it for Kafka, ElasticSearch, JDBC, etc.

Comment: You might want to read through [OpenTracing](https://github.com/opentracing/opentracing-java) or if you are using Amazon services [XRay](https://aws.amazon.com/de/xray/). They work similarly name things differently however. There are plenty more frameworks for distributed tracing out there.

Comment: Thanks, @Mike and Roman, I didn't know about the OpenTracing specification or the Zipkin implementation of it until your comments mentioned it. Looking into it now.